# Stored Procedure Count

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

I am trying to get a dynamic count to print out but it is telling me 
 @totalCAUUpdates needs a scalar value. Any thoughts?

```
declare @totalCAUUpdates as int = 0;
   declare @realTableName as varchar(100) = '[_TEMP_SubscriptionTransactionsForMosoPay09022014]'
   declare @updateSQL as varchar(1000) = 'select @totalCAUUpdates = count(*) from ' + @realTableName + ' where len(accountNumberUpdated) > 0 OR len(accountAccessoryUpdated) > 0;';
   raiserror (@updateSQL, 0,1) with nowait;
   EXEC (@updateSQL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @totalCAUUpdates INT= 0;
DECLARE @updateSQL NVARCHAR(MAX); 
DECLARE @realTableName SYSNAME;

SET @realTableName  = '_TEMP_SubscriptionTransactionsForMosoPay09022014';

SET @updateSQL = N'select @totalCAUUpdates = count(*) from ' + QUOTENAME(@realTableName) 
              + N' where len(accountNumberUpdated) > 0 OR len(accountAccessoryUpdated) > 0;';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @updateSQL
                    ,N'@totalCAUUpdates INT OUTPUT'
                    ,@totalCAUUpdates OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 1):

your batch is being executed inside another session, where @totalCAUUpdates  is not visible.
You need to use [sp_ExecuteSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) instead.. This proc allows you to pass in values declared in the calling session and use them with a declared variable in the called session

Comment: how could I use sp_ExecuteSQL effective in this sproc?